# How to add log_tags in Sidekiq log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, sidekiq

I want to add custom log_tags in Sidekiq logs.
In rails we are able to add in following manner

**application.rb
  config.log_tags = ['TestLog']**

Is there any way to add like this in Sidekiq Log ?

Comment: Sidekiq spawns the rails application instance only, so I don't think you can set different tags for sidekiq process.

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging#customize-logger-format